# in mybatis why this sql work but another don't?

Tags: mybatis

today i write a sql like this

```
<select id="selectVoByEtpsId" parameterType="java.lang.String"
        resultMap="BaseResultMap" >
        SELECT P.ETPS_APTT_PUTREC_ID, P.ETPS_ID, P.PARA_CD,P.PARA_VAL,
        C.PARA_NAME,C.PARA_TYPE,C.PARA_SEQNO,P.CREATE_USER, P.INDB_TIME, P.UPDATE_USER,P.UPDATE_TIME  
        FROM USER_ETPS_APTT_PUTREC P
        RIGHT JOIN USER_ETPS_APTT_CONFIG C
        ON ETPS_ID=#{etpsId,JDBCTYPE=VARCHAR}
        AND P.PARA_CD=C.PARA_CD
    </select>
```

but i get error like this

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.dao.IUserEtpsApttPutrecDao.BaseResultMap
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:120)
```

when i change sql to this

```
<select id="selectVoByEtpsId" parameterType="java.lang.String"
    resultMap="BaseResultMap" >
    SELECT P.ETPS_APTT_PUTREC_ID, P.ETPS_ID, P.PARA_CD,P.PARA_VAL,
    C.PARA_NAME,C.PARA_TYPE,C.PARA_SEQNO,P.CREATE_USER, P.INDB_TIME, P.UPDATE_USER,P.UPDATE_TIME  
    FROM USER_ETPS_APTT_PUTREC P
    RIGHT JOIN USER_ETPS_APTT_CONFIG C
    ON ETPS_ID=#{etpsId}
    AND P.PARA_CD=C.PARA_CD
</select>
```

it works.
can anyone tell me why? thanks.

Comment: only  change line ON ETPS_ID=#{etpsId}

Answer (score 0):

The error message states there are duplicate result map definitions with id `BaseResultMap`.

Furthermore, case for property names must be respected. Write `ETPS_ID=#{etpsId,jdbcType=VARCHAR}` or expect *Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration* if you leave uppercase.